# Why the filter does not work when the back button of the browser is pressed in laravel?

Tags: php, authentication, browser, laravel, laravel-4

I have a view to enter an account, then called the controller where the data is validated and are then saved with the method of authentication

```
    public function doLogin(){
    $rules = array(
                    'email' => 'required|email',
                    'password' => 'required'
                    );

    $validator = Validator::make(Input::all(), $rules);
    //dd(Input::all());

    if($validator->fails()){
        return Redirect::to('usuarios')->withErrors($validator)->withInput(Input::except('password'));
    }else{

        $userdata = array(
            'email' => Input::get('email'),
            'password' => Input::get('password')
            );

        if(Auth::attempt($userdata)){
            return View::make('principal');
        }else{

            return Redirect::to('usuarios');
        }

    }
}
```

I also have the function to exit the session

```
Route::get('usuarios/logout', function(){
        Auth::logout();
        return Redirect::to('usuarios'); //login page
})->before('auth');
```

The problem is that when I press the back button of the browser, I can use without problems the application but without the authentication.

**Route**

```
Route::get('usuarios', function(){
return View::make('login');
})->before('guest');

Route::get('usuarios/view', function(){
    $usuarios = Usuario::paginate(5);
    return View::make('viewusuario', array('usuarios' => $usuarios));
})->before('auth');

Route::get('usuario/create', function(){
    return View::make('formusuario');
})->before('auth');
```

**Filter**

```
Route::filter('auth', function()
{
    if (Auth::guest()) return Redirect::guest('usuarios'); //login page
});
Route::filter('guest', function()
{
    if (Auth::check()){
        return View::make('principal'); //home page     
    }
});
```

How can I fix it?

Comment: because it is the browser cache - it is not 'reloading' your page.

Comment: and by use you mean see ?

Comment: Instead of use, the user will *see* but will not be able to do anything...

Comment: @zhelon people are saying this is the cache, which may well be true for hitting the back button, but I guess the question I can ask which will discern this or not is: after logging out and then hitting back, can you then *use* the app as if logged in? So, not just being able to see the previous screen as if logged in, but actual actions from that page, or as soon as you do an action does it ask you to log in?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is related to *browser cache*, not Laravel.

To handle browser cache you can use the following code in one of your *start files* or in a *service provider*:

```
App::after(function($request, $response)
{
    $response->headers->set('Cache-Control','nocache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate');
    $response->headers->set('Pragma','no-cache');
    $response->headers->set('Expires','Fri, 01 Jan 1990 00:00:00 GMT');
});
```

Here we are just modifying each responses within Laravel using [application events](http://laravel.com/docs/lifecycle#application-events).

---

Some people said that this works for all web browser but not for IE. So for IE, you should add a bunch of meta tags to your layout:

```
<meta http-equiv="cache-control" content="max-age=0" />
<meta http-equiv="cache-control" content="no-cache" />
<meta http-equiv="cache-control" content="no-store" />
<meta http-equiv="cache-control" content="must-revalidate" />
<meta http-equiv="expires"       content="0" />
<meta http-equiv="expires"       content="Tue, 01 Jan 1980 1:00:00 GMT" />
<meta http-equiv="pragma"        content="no-cache" />
```

Comment: I must put this conde in ``app/config/app.php`` ?

Comment: Tested it on several IE versions and it always worked correctly. In my example i used only the first two headers (`Cache-control` and `Pragma`) and did not set any meta tags.

Comment: @zhelon - The `App::after(…)` event is defined in the "filters.php" file.

Comment: Thank very much, this work very good. I opened the bounty coz I don't understand your code and I asked you but there was no response :D

Comment: This resulted in white flashes between loading the pages in chrome. Maybe any suggestion for that?

Comment: This doesn't work on Firefox 45, the browser still shows cache page on back press.

Answer (score 0):

The problem lies in the browser cache, when you go back, the browser doesn't query everything, for the sake of speed it just loads the page from cache. But when you reload that page `ctrl + r` it won't work. You can disable page caching like other people said here, but it will cost you the performance of the website and more bills if you are on a cloud hosting. So cache is good, keep it.

You should try to group all the pages that need `auth` filter so you don't forget to add that filter, we're all human, sometimes we forget.

```
Route::group(['before' => 'auth', function(){
    Route::get('usarios/view', function() { ... });
    Route::get('usarios/create', function() { ... });
}]);

Route::group(['before' => 'guest', function(){
    Route::get('usarios/login', 'AuthController@showLogin');
    Route::post('usarios/login', 'AuthController@doLogin');
}]);
```

Also, try to not display the main user page in the login `post`, in your case `doLogin`. You should redirect the user to a new page showing the user home page.