# Laravel - how to stop remembering users

Tags: php, laravel, remember-me

I'm new to laravel and added a userauthentification to my application. Now I don't want authenticated users to be remembered after closing the browser, but this is actually the case. How do I stop this? The remember_token is a nullable varchar(100), an it is set with the first login and then updated everytime the user logs out.

Shouldn't users only be remembered when i pass true as parameter in the auth::attempt()?

Tyvm in advance...

This is part of my model:

```
$validation = Validator::make($input, $rules, $messages);

if ($validation->fails())
{
    $this->response['message'] = $validation->getMessageBag()->first();
}
else
{
    $this->response['message'] = $messages['user.missing'];

    if (Auth::attempt(array(
        'emailadress' => $input['emailadress'],
        'password' => $input['password'])))
    {
        $this->response['valid'] = true;
        $this->response['message'] = 'Hey '.Auth::user()->firstname.'!';
        $this->response['redirect'] = '/hello';
    }
}

return $this->response;
```

Comment: The remember_token is updated even if you do not use the remember functionallity, this doesn't mean that the user is remembered after closing the browser. Did you test it?

Comment: Yes, the remember_token is always updated on logout.. but my users are always remembered after closing and reopening the browser, unless i set 'expire_on_close' to false in the 'config/session.php'. This shouldn't be, right?

Comment: As far as i know this shouldn't be (i deactivated the remember_token though). Could this possibly be a caching issue like this http://stackoverflow.com/q/23916096/575765 ?

Answer (score 0):

As you said, you are not including the remember parameter in Auth::attempt(), so indeed - your users are *not* being remembered.

They will be logged in for as long as their session remains active.  Browsers don't empty their cookies upon closing unless the user specifically tells it to, and there is certainly no way for you to "detect" their browser closing from the server-side and expire their session from that end.

So, you must either choose a different session lifetime in your PHP settings if you want sessions to expire more quickly, or [you can do something like this](http://forumsarchive.laravel.io/viewtopic.php?pid=11881#p11881) where you timestamp their activities and log them out if they've been idle for a set time.

If you choose to shorten your session lifetimes, this can be accomplished in `php.ini`:

```
ini_set(‘session.gc_maxlifetime’,30);
ini_set(‘session.gc_probability’,1);
ini_set(‘session.gc_divisor’,1);
```